# Stateful Expression visitors multiple run issue

Tags: c#, expression, linq-expressions, visitor-pattern

Let's say I need to write an expression visitor, which also uses some injectable service, hence it has to have a public constructor, and cannot be simply wrapped in a static facade.

```
public class ProcessingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {

  IProcessor _processor;
  public string Result { get; private set; }

  public ProcessingVisitor(IProcessor processor) {
    _processor = processor;
  }

  protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
  {
    // visit left and right
    // ... and do something with _processor
    Result += // ... append something to result
    return node;
  }
}
```

Now when I want to use this visitor, I would instantiate it and use it like this

```
var myExpression = ...;
var myVisitor = new ProcessingVisitor();
myVisitor.Visit(myExpression);
var result = myVisitor.Result;
```

Now imagine I - for example by accident - run `Visit` on another expression. Then `Result` will contain both results concatenated. How can I make such a visitor completely "fool proof"? Where could I reset the `Result`? I could override `Visit`, but I don't know inside if it's called first time, or it's called in the middle of the processing, so I can't reset it there.

Comment: Could you post the code for `Visit` - maybe it is in `ExpressionVisitor`? Also, is the parameterless `ProcessingVisitor` constructor correct?

Comment: Yes it is an Expression visitor descendant. The parameterless constructor is a mistake, I'll correct it, thank you.

Comment: From a pure architecture point of view, your gripe is that you added state to your class, but you find that state could lead to invalid state. The solution is simple. Remove the state. Make the method call to parse the expression tree return the string, or a tupple with the visited expression and string

Comment: @Aron Except that the design of the built-in ExpressionVisitor doesn't allow doing this, because the overridable methods return `Expression` or some other expression tree object.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Sure you can. There is a THIRD option (which isn't a third option if you are a functional programmer who is well versed with the concept of "Referential transparency"), `return new FooExpressionVisitor(myState).Visit(tree);`.

Comment: @Aron But what happens if I call `.Visit` again? `var visitor = new FooExpressionVisitor(myState); visitor.Visit(tree); return visitor.Visit(tree);` If `Visit` could be modified somehow to return state that would be a different story; but the signature of `ExpressionVisitor.Visit` is to only return an `Expression`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work (overriding `Visit` to track what your root node is):

```
public class ProcessingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{

    IProcessor _processor;
    private Expression _rootExpression = null;
    public string Result { get; private set; }

    public ProcessingVisitor(IProcessor processor)
    {
        _processor = processor;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        // visit left and right
        // ... and do something with _processor
        Result += "";// ... append something to result
        return node;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if (_rootExpression == null)
        {
            _rootExpression = node;
            Result = null;
        }

        var toReturn = base.Visit(node);

        if (_rootExpression == node)
            _rootExpression = null;
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an internal class to separate your initializing from your visiting:

```
public class ProcessingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{

    IProcessor _processor;

    #region Inner Class
    internal class _Implementation : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        IProcessor _processor;
        internal string Result { get; set; }

        internal _Implementation(IProcessor processor)
        {
            _processor = processor;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
        {
            // visit left and right
            // ... and do something with _processor
            Result += "";// ... append something to result
            return node;
        }

        internal Expression VisitFresh(Expression node)
        {
            Result = null;
            return base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public string Result { get; private set; }
    public ProcessingVisitor(IProcessor processor)
    {
        _processor = processor;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        var impl = new _Implementation(_processor);
        var toReturn = impl.VisitFresh(node);
        Result = impl.Result;
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes this is kind of a solution but still not fool proof as one could naively use the Visit method. And c# doesn't offer a way to hide a publicly inherited member.

Comment: I like your first idea to track the state of the visitor. However I would improve it a bit. Instead of tracking the root expression, we could possibly introduce a simple integer field which would increment before `base.Visit` and decrement afterwards. We could check if its the initial state by comparing this field with 0. I think this would be more simple and clean. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah that would work too. Or if you wanted a stack: `if(!_stack.Any()) Result = ""; _stack.Push(expression); base.Visit(expression); _stack.Pop();` Same idea. Depending on what you're doing, the parent expressions in the stack could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your visitor in another class, make it private and make sure that one visitor instance is created for each usage. For instance here as an extension method in a static class:

```
public static class ExpressionProcessingExtensions
{
    public static Expression Process(this Expression expression, IProcessor processor)
    {
        var visitor = new ProcessingVisitor(processor);
        visitor.Visit(expression);
        return visitor.Result;
    }

    private class ProcessingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {

      IProcessor _processor;
      public string Result { get; private set; }

      public ProcessingVisitor(IProcessor processor) {
        _processor = processor;
      }

      protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
      {
        // visit left and right
        // ... and do something with _processor
        Result += // ... append something to result
        return node;
      }
    }
}
```